# Migrating from richfaces 3.3.2 to richfaces 4.0.0 final

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm trying to migrate a web application from richfaces 3.3.2 to 4.0.0 so I changed the necessary stuff in the web.xml file (servlet mapping ".xhtml" and removed Ajax4jsf Filter).
I also changed the richfaces 3 jars to the 4th version but now I've got some errors and don't know how to resolve them:

```
The import org.ajax4jsf cannot be resolved
The import org.ajax4jsf cannot be resolved
The import org.ajax4jsf cannot be resolved
The import org.richfaces cannot be resolved
The import org.richfaces cannot be resolved
The import org.richfaces cannot be resolved
Incompatible conditional operand types UIComponent and UICalendar
UICalendar cannot be resolved to a type
HtmlToolTip cannot be resolved to a type
HtmlToolTip cannot be resolved to a type
HtmlToolTip cannot be resolved to a type
Incompatible conditional operand types UIViewRoot and AjaxViewRoot
AjaxViewRoot cannot be resolved to a type
AjaxViewRoot cannot be resolved to a type
org.ajax4jsf cannot be resolved to a type
EventsQueue cannot be resolved to a type
HtmlAjaxSupport cannot be resolved to a type
HtmlToolTip cannot be resolved to a type
Incompatible conditional operand types UIComponent and HtmlCalendar
HtmlCalendar cannot be resolved to a type
HtmlToolTip cannot be resolved to a type
HtmlToolTip cannot be resolved to a type
HtmlToolTip cannot be resolved to a type
HtmlToolTip cannot be resolved to a type
HtmlToolTip cannot be resolved to a type
```

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Migration from v3 to v4 is quite a mess, many things has changed. Your project is build with Ant or Maven ? maybe you're missing some librairies or wrong references in your classpath. Can you add more details about your project ?

Comment: the problem is that de migration guide is not complete.my project is build without maven. it was workin fine with the v3 jars so i just replaced them with the v4 jars.(richfaces-api-4.0.0.Final.jar, richfaces-impl-4.0.0.Final.jar and richfaces-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar).

Comment: richfaces-ui-3.3.2.SR1.jar may correct those errors. i'm wondering why the v4 doesn't contain the same specification as v3 !

Comment: if i remember well, some libraires' names has changed with v4. Try    richfaces-components-ui

Comment: thanks for your help but the problem is still the same

Comment: Do you have richfaces-core-impl in your libraries ? AjaxViewRoot seems to be there : http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.0.X/4.0.0.Alpha2/en-US/javadocs/richfaces-core-impl/org/ajax4jsf/component/AjaxViewRoot.html

Answer (score 0):

Missing richfaces-core-impl library

[Javadoc AjaxViewRoot v4](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.0.X/4.0.0.Alpha2/en-US/javadocs/richfaces-core-impl/org/ajax4jsf/component/AjaxViewRoot.html)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the RichFaces 3.3 Ajax Filter in web.xml file

```
         <filter>
                <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
                <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
          </filter>

            <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
                <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
                <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
                <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
                <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
            </filter-mapping>
```

RichFaces 4.0.0 final open webmvc-config.xml file add this

```
       <bean id="flowController" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
            <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
            <property name="ajaxHandler">
                <bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfAjaxHandler" />
            </property>
        </bean>
```