# Unable to use f:ajax with jsf 2.0

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I've updated JSF from 1.2_09 to 2.0.3 (both `jsf-api` and `jsf-impl` jars) but still can't use `f:ajax` tag on the web-page.The following exception is thrown:

```
ERROR 20:07:36 [org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:199)] : Exception in the filter chain
javax.servlet.ServletException: /trackers.jspx @34,72 <f:ajax> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core, but no tag was defined for name: ajax
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321) ~[jsf-api-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178) [richfaces-impl-3.3.2.SR1.jar:3.3.2.SR1]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290) [richfaces-impl-3.3.2.SR1.jar:3.3.2.SR1]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388) [richfaces-impl-3.3.2.SR1.jar:3.3.2.SR1]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515) [richfaces-impl-3.3.2.SR1.jar:3.3.2.SR1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at ua.com.winforce.loto_partner.site.web.filters.PartnerAccessFilter.doFilter(PartnerAccessFilter.java:143) [partner_site_commons-1.2.4.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.concurrent.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilterHttp(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:99) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175) [spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236) [spring-web-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167) [spring-web-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [?:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: com.sun.facelets.tag.TagException: /trackers.jspx @34,72 <f:ajax> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core, but no tag was defined for name: ajax
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.CompilationManager.pushTag(CompilationManager.java:193) ~[jsf-facelets-1.1.15.jar:1.1.15]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler$CompilationHandler.startElement(SAXCompiler.java:194) ~[jsf-facelets-1.1.15.jar:1.1.15]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:232) ~[jsf-facelets-1.1.15.jar:1.1.15]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:105) ~[jsf-facelets-1.1.15.jar:1.1.15]
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:218) ~[jsf-facelets-1.1.15.jar:1.1.15]
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:149) ~[jsf-facelets-1.1.15.jar:1.1.15]
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:100) ~[jsf-facelets-1.1.15.jar:1.1.15]
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:519) ~[jsf-facelets-1.1.15.jar:1.1.15]
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:569) ~[jsf-facelets-1.1.15.jar:1.1.15]
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100) ~[richfaces-api-3.3.2.SR1.jar:3.3.2.SR1]
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176) ~[richfaces-impl-3.3.2.SR1.jar:3.3.2.SR1]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117) ~[jsf-impl-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97) ~[jsf-impl-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135) ~[jsf-impl-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309) ~[jsf-api-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 60 more
Nov 28, 2014 8:07:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/loto_partner_site_millhouse] threw exception [/trackers.jspx @34,72 <f:ajax> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core, but no tag was defined for name: ajax] with root cause
com.sun.facelets.tag.TagException: /trackers.jspx @34,72 <f:ajax> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core, but no tag was defined for name: ajax
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.CompilationManager.pushTag(CompilationManager.java:193)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler$CompilationHandler.startElement(SAXCompiler.java:194)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:232)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:105)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:218)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:149)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:100)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:519)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:569)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at ua.com.winforce.loto_partner.site.web.filters.PartnerAccessFilter.doFilter(PartnerAccessFilter.java:143)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.concurrent.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilterHttp(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Honestly, I have no idea why the exception was thrown. While Tomcat was starting there was the message:

> INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.3 (SNAPSHOT 20100726) for context
>   '/project_sun_player' Dec 01, 2014 11:30:25 AM
>   com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance

Which means JSF 2.0.3 is being used. Any suggestion?

UPD Libraries I'm using are:

```
spring-beans-2.5.5.jar
spring-dao-2.0.8.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar
spring-aop-2.5.5.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
spring-jdbc-2.5.5.jar
spring-tx-2.5.5.jar
hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
jta-1.1.jar
hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar
ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar
activation-1.1.jar
httpclient-4.0-beta2.jar
httpcore-4.0-beta3.jar
log4j-1.2.14.jar
persistence-api-1.0.jar
raven-5.0.1.jar
guava-17.0.jar
jackson-core-2.4.2.jar
raven-log4j2-5.0.1.jar
jdbcappender-2.1.01.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar
commons-pool-1.2.jar
commons-discovery-0.4.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-validator-1.4.0.jar
spring-orm-2.5.5.jar
spring-support-2.0.8.jar
spring-security-taglibs-2.0.3.jar
spring-security-acl-2.0.3.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar
hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar
ehcache-1.2.3.jar
asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar
cglib-2.1_3.jar
asm-1.5.3.jar
el-functors-1.0.3.jar
javassist-3.10.0.GA.jar
jcaptcha-all-1.0-RC6.jar
json-lib-2.2.3-jdk15.jar
ezmorph-1.0.6.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
jsp-api-2.1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jsf-api-2.0.3.jar
jsf-impl-2.0.3.jar
el-impl-1.0.jar
jsf-facelets-1.1.11.jar
aspectjrt-1.5.3.jar
aspectjweaver-1.5.3.jar
xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
jcommon-1.0.12.jar
richfaces-api-3.3.2.SR1.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
richfaces-impl-jsf2-3.3.3.Final.jar
commons-digester-1.8.1.jar
richfaces-ui-3.3.2.SR1.jar
richfaces-impl-3.3.2.SR1.jar
spring-web-2.5.5.jar
spring-context-2.5.5.jar
spring-core-2.5.5.jar
postgresql-8.3-603.jdbc4.jar
mail-1.4.1.jar
quartz-1.5.2.jar
freemarker-2.3.9.jar
junit-4.5.jar
avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar
saaj-impl-1.3.1.jar
saaj-api-1.3.jar
```

Comment: You need to update Richfaces 3 to Richfaces 4 as well, I guess.

Comment: Also please list down the libraries you are using currently after you have upgraded the JSF jars.  This will be helpful to find if there is any conflicts between jars.

Comment: @mvg sure, couldn't you look at the libraries list I provided?

Comment: Have you updated Richfaces Jars from version 3 to 4?

Comment: @mvg No, not yet. Is it painfuless?

Comment: This might be helpful http://richfaces.jboss.org/docs/3-x-4-x-migration

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402588/migrating-from-richfaces-3-3-2-to-richfaces-4-0-0-final

Comment: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/165063?tstart=0 . RF3.3 is not compatible with JSF-2